# Number of comparisons when building a binary search tree

Tags: comparison, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am learning binary search trees by myself. There is a question that asks how many comparisons it takes to build a tree when inserting the letters E, A, S, Y, Q, U, E, S, T, I, O and N in an initially empty tree.

I drew the binary search tree and I counted the number of comparisons when inserting each element.

```
 E 
/ \
A  S
   /\
  Q  Y
 /   /
 E   U
 \   /
  I  S
   \  \
    O  T
    /
    N
```

I got 36.

Is that correct? Also, is there another way to know the number of comparisons without having to draw the tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of comparisons will be 36 .

You can conclude that **maximum number of comparisons** to insert an element in BST will not be more than **height of the tree**.

Answer (score 0):

For me, The number of comparisons I got is 48.

The maximum number of comparisons in this build is as follows:

1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 6 + 7 = 48

Each element insertion comparison follows this: (1 + depth of the node). Thus, if I add up all the comparisons for the elements to insert, to build the BST, I will get the above answer of 48.